# I need a faster way to find repos with PyGitHub

Tags: pygithub

My organization has a ton of repos in GitHub.  I have a subset of these repos that I want to programmatically detect.  All of the repos I want start with the same string.
The code below correctly finds them, but it takes about a minute to do it because of all of the repos present.  Is there a faster way to do this?

```
def FindMyRepos():
  global ACCESS_TOKEN, ORGANIZATION, PREFIX
  repos = []
  # Log into GitHub
  gh = Github(ACCESS_TOKEN)
  if not gh: return 1
  # Connect to organization
  org = gh.get_organization(ORGANIZATION)
  if not org: return 2
  # Look for repos that start with PREFIX
  for r in org.get_repos():
    if r.name.startswith(PREFIX):
      repos.append(r.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I have found the answer.  I need to use the search_repositories method.  The one 'gotcha' is that this method is part of the Github object but not the organization object.

```
def FindMyRepos():
  global ACCESS_TOKEN, ORGANIZATION, PREFIX
  repos = []
  # Log into GitHub
  gh = Github(ACCESS_TOKEN)
  if not gh: return 1
  # Look for repos in ORGANIZATION containing PREFIX
  for r in gh.search_repositorires(query=ORGANIZATION+'/'+PREFIX):
    # Only include repos starting with PREFIX
    if r.name.startswith(PREFIX):
      repos.append(r.name)
```

The reason for the if r.name.startswith(PREFIX) is because for some reason the search will return all repos in the ORGANIZATION that have the string PREFIX in their name anywhere.